# requests.session to initialize session and input search terms

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to create a function that goes to [this website](https://shop.jewelosco.com/ecom/home) and input the zip code in the field and subsequently perform itemized searches, like "chicken" in the search box.  I began with this.

```
import requests
s = requests.session()
input_data = {"Register_ZipCode": "60637"}
r = s.post("https://shop.jewelosco.com/ecom/home", login_data)
r2 = s.get("https://shop.jewelosco.com/ecom/home")
```

After this, I want to somehow retain the input information above and run a search as below.

```
chicken = request.get("https://shop.jewelosco.com/ecom/search?source=searchBox&searchTerm=chicken")
```

Where I can finally begin scraping the html data.

I'm stuck on checking if the zip code has been inputted correctly and how to then use that session to conduct a search while retaining session formation (location).

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Acquiring the required data:

Looking at the page source, the form which submits the data (zipcode) is:

```
<form action="/ecom/account/sign-in" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="form" value="ZipCode" />
    <div class="field id-ZipCode">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="Zip Code is required." data-val-sdcexactlength="Zip Code must be 5 characters long." data-val-sdcexactlength-max="5" data-val-sdcexactlength-min="5" data-val-sdcnumeric="Zip Code must contain numeric characters only." data-val-sdcnumeric-pattern="^[0-9]*$" id="Register_ZipCode" maxlength="5" name="Register.ZipCode" placeholder="Enter Your Zip Code" type="text" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-getstarted  submit btn-round " onclick="javascript:trackLinkZipGetStarted();">
        <input class="submit btn-round " name="Browse" type="submit" value="    Get Started    "></input>
    </div>
</form>
```

I've removed some `<div>` tags as they are irrelevant.

From this form, the information we need is:

1. `URL = 'https://shop.jewelosco.com/ecom/account/sign-in'`
2. `method="post"` implies we've to use `requests.post()`
3. `data = {'form': 'ZipCode', 'Register.ZipCode': '60637', 'Browse': '    Get Started    '}`

(**Note:** You've to provide all the values that are included in the `<input>` tag in the form data using `name` as key and `value` as value.)

---

## Sending the data:

Code to send the zipcode:

```
data = {'form': 'ZipCode', 'Register.ZipCode': '60637', 'Browse': '    Get Started    '}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post('https://shop.jewelosco.com/ecom/account/sign-in', data=data)
```

If you check the response history and current url, you'll see that it is getting redirected to `https://shop.jewelosco.com/ecom/home` which is url we want to fetch the data from.

```
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.url
https://shop.jewelosco.com/ecom/home
>>> r.history
[<Response [302]>]
```

To check whether we've successfully posted this data you can use this:

```
>>> 'Top Offers &amp; Shopping Tools' in r.text
True
```

---

## Searching for items:

Now that we've successfully posted the zipcode, you can use this `Session` object (`s`) to search for anything you want.

Complete code:

```
data = {'form': 'ZipCode', 'Register.ZipCode': '60637', 'Browse': '    Get Started    '}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post('https://shop.jewelosco.com/ecom/account/sign-in', data=data)
    r = s.get('https://shop.jewelosco.com/ecom/search?source=searchBox&searchTerm=chicken')
    print('Perdue Chicken Ground Fresh - 16 Oz' in r.text)
    # prints 'True'
```

Comment: I have one more question.  When I ran it once, it worked fine, however for some reason when I call the exact code again, I now get a 400 error.  Any idea why?

Comment: Actually, I ran the code multiple times right now without any errors. Are you sure you didn't change anything? If you changed the search term, first, check whether the link is working in a normal browser.

Comment: So the post works correctly every time, but the get line gives a 400 error.  The code is exactly the same.  This occurs when I exit the ipython terminal and run the exact code again.

Comment: The only reason this could happen is if your using a bad url. A bad url gives a 400 error code. But as you are saying you're not changing the code, I can't say why this is happening. Are you still getting the errors?

Comment: Ah sorry your code is fine, the issue was Perdue Chicken was not in the search results, because the ads changed.  Thank you so much! :)